# JavaScript doesn't run inside instagram app?

Tags: javascript, instagram, shopify, liquid

When I open my website inside instagram app it doesn't run all of my scripts,.. 
I'm using shopify with liquid, and the wierd part is that half of the scripts does work and other half simply doesn't.

I'm calling scripts inside theme.liquid and actual scripts are inside assets folder. I tried writing the code direct in the template inside `{{% javascript %}}` tag, but that doesn't work either. It all works when the page is opened inside web browser but in instagram everything gets messed up !

Also I noticed that some of my styles don't apply either, What I'm I missing here? I'm calling my scripts like this: (these 2 actually work)

```
{{ 'slick.min.js'  | asset_url | script_tag     }}  
{{ 'flashTimer.js'  | asset_url | script_tag     }}
```

Comment: Your question presumes the existence of a full-featured web browser inside the Instagram app.  I'm not sure that's a reasonable assumption.

Comment: I don't think It's is full featured web browser,.. but I think I should be able to alert a message on my screen? I also get that some of the new css properties maybe won't work, but media queries should work?

Comment: Hard to say without detailed browser specifications.

Comment: Ok forget about browser specification,.. But why is that 3 of my scripts run normaly and the other 2 won't start at all? That is my main concern. I didn't try to put everything inside the one that work, since I want to make some order,. I will do it now, just to check, but I imagine it will work.

Comment: And what I'm saying is that it appears that the browser in Instagram doesn't support the things you're asking it to do.

Comment: Ok, I just checked on different phone and everything is working fine ! Now I'm confused even more,.. I guess there is something about android version or some other updates

Comment: @tr4nc3 it's been a while since your post, but did you manage to get a fix for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved this problem but for those who came from google and could not, I wanted to write the solution. Instagram holds too many caches, actually this is the main problem. A site opened with an Instagram story link probably fetches pre-opened cache files. The only way to solve this is when the browser is opened, go to the settings in the top right 3 points and clear the browser cache. That's how I solved this problem.